# Can robot_localization be used with Noetic?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is robot_localization not available for ROS Noeic?

I git clone the "robot_localization" Package and tried to do a "catkin build", but it skips as follows.

```
[build] Warning: Skipping package `robot_localization` because it has an unsupported package build type: `ament_cmake`
[build] Note: Available build types:                                           
[build]  - `catkin`                                                            
[build]  - `cmake`
```

From my research, it seems that "ament_cmake" is a ROS2 specific build tool and cannot be used with Noetic. Please let me know if I am wrong.

Is there any way to use robot_localization with ROS Noetic?

Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/409325/can-robot_localization-be-used-with-noetic?/) by [donguri](https://answers.ros.org/users/113638/donguri/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2022-11-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> Can robot_localization be used with Noetic?

Yes.

Below are the two ways to install [robot_localization](http://wiki.ros.org/robot_localization) in ROS Noetic:

1. **Install from Pre-built Binaries (Preferred):** Please use the following command:

   ```
    $ sudo apt install ros-noetic-robot-localization
   ```
2. **Install from Source:** To answer you completely, I tried this approach as well. Please see below:

   ```
    $ cd ros_ws/src
       $ git clone https://github.com/cra-ros-pkg/robot_localization.git --branch noetic-devel
    $ cd ros_ws/
       $ rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src -r -y
    $ catkin_make -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release
   ```

---

Originally posted by [ravijoshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25207/ravijoshi/) with karma: 1744 on 2022-11-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [donguri](https://answers.ros.org/users/113638/donguri/) on 2022-11-14**:
Thank you for your prompt reply.

I can't try it right away, but I will certainly try it soon.

Thank you very much.

**Comment by [ravijoshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25207/ravijoshi/) on 2022-11-17**:\

> I can't try it right away, but I will certainly try it soon.

Does it work?

**Comment by [donguri](https://answers.ros.org/users/113638/donguri/) on 2022-11-18**:
Dear ravijoshi.

Thank you for your patience.
And thank you for your advice.

Thanks to you, everything went well.

The only thing I did was change `$ catkin_make -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release` part to `$ catkin build`.

**Comment by [ravijoshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25207/ravijoshi/) on 2022-11-19**:
I am glad you made it work!